# Using setTimeout to temporarily change div background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm try to create an effect that loops through each of four divs and changes their color to green before changing it back to the original and moving on to the next one. Right now it is just permanently changing the colors. I'm not sure how to fix this so that the color changes back before moving on to the next one, because I am 'deleting' each prior element in order to loop properly. I'm probably doing seven things wrong, and would appreciate any advice.

Here's a working JSBin:https://jsbin.com/puricazuxa/4/edit?html,css,js,output

Javascript:

```
arrayCount=[1,2,3,4];
var secondPrint = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
if (arrayCount.length>0){
      $("#button"+arrayCount[0]).attr("class", "sButton2");

     arrayCount.shift(1);
     secondPrint();
   }
}    ,1000);
  };

secondPrint();
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  font-family: "Arial";

}
.sButton{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display:inline;
  background-color: rgb(50,100,100);
}
.sButton2{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display:inline;
  background-color: rgb(100,200,100);
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<!-- Main page placeholders -->

<br/>
<br/>
<div class = "sButton" id="button1">1</div>
<div class = "sButton" id="button2">2</div>
<div class = "sButton" id="button3">3</div>
<div class = "sButton" id="button4">4</div>
```

Comment: Tips: 1) Don't use implicit globals (without `var`). 2) An element can have more than one class, so in jQuery instead of using `attr('class')` you should use `addClass` and `removeClass`; you should also change your CSS to take advantage of this and reduce repetition.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I had forgotten about addClass and removeClass. Appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is a little flawed here. A better approach would be to use `setInterval()` to update the state of the buttons each second, moving to the next one on each call of the function. Try this:

```
var secondPrint = function() {
    var $buttons = $('.sButton');
    var $active = $buttons.filter('.sButton2');
    $active = (!$active.length || $active.is(':last')) ? $('.sButton:first') : $active.next();
    $buttons.removeClass('sButton2');
    $active.addClass('sButton2');
};

setInterval(secondPrint, 1000)
secondPrint();
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0x20xqnn/)

> how do I make it stop after one iteration through them all? I hadn't used setInterval() because I didn't want it to go on forever

In that case you just need to amend the logic check to clear the interval if the `:last` condition hits, like this:

```
var interval;
var secondPrint = function() {
    var $buttons = $('.sButton');
    var $active = $buttons.filter('.sButton2');
    $buttons.removeClass('sButton2');
    if ($active.is(':last')) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }

    $active = !$active.length ? $('.sButton:first') : $active.next();
    $active.addClass('sButton2');
};

interval = setInterval(secondPrint, 1000)
secondPrint();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0x20xqnn/2/)

Comment: This is great, but how do I make it stop after one iteration through them all? I hadn't used setInterval() because I didn't want it to go on forever.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out using clearInterval(). Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I updated my answer for you anyway